# Why Activity Callbacks Such as onPause , onStop and onDestroy are not invoked when Asynctask is involved

Tags: android-asynctask

when i create an Async task in Activity A and while the task is still executing , if i press back button in Activity A , activity callbacks such as onPause , onStop and onDestroy are not invoked.

Not able to understand why ?

Answer (score 0):

while an `Asynctask` is running background you cannot interrupt it,
and the activity may not pause, stop or destroy (even if you can, Asynctask will still running).

> UNLESS

you call `cancel(true)` to kill the Asynctask or check `isCancelled()` to verify if Asynctask is still running background.